# Expression value

Tags: javascript

I have these declarations:

```
var a;
var b = 1;
var c = 2;
var d = a || b, c;
```

`d` is  1 , so what is the meaning of the `,c` in the expression?

Comment: It seems to serve to nothing here, as c is already declared.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The construct

```
var d=a||b, c;
```

does two things :

- it declares `d` and assigns it the value `a||b`
- it declares the `c` variable

As `c` was already declared, I'd say it's totally useless.

Answer (score 3):

`var d = a || b, c;` simply means `var d = a || b; var c;` "comma" is used to separate multiple variables' declaration. Here `,c` is not needed as `var c = 2;` is already defining `c`.

Answer (score 2):

Your code is effectively interpreted like this:

```
var a; // Variable declarations are hoisted to top of scope
var b;
var c;
var d;

b = 1;
c = 2;
d = a || b;
```

So the final `c` declaration is doing nothing at all. Note that `var x = y, z;` is simply a *variable statement* that contains two declarations (one of which includes an assignment).